# grunt build css encoding

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

Static project using yeoman -webapp

I have a UTF checkmark within my .scss files:

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px; left: 0px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:$color-primary;
  transition: all .2s;
}
```

In my compiled .css, the content has been butchered:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

div.checkbox [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: 'Ô£ö';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #76C001;
  transition: all .2s; }
```

[Gruntfile.js gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d239d74cd6a16f457f9)

Would love if someone could enlighten me on the why's and/or fixes.  Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/h3ky89wa/

```
p:before {
   content: '\2714';
}
```

Comment: This appears to do it.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @lkiernan thanks, please vote for the answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but try the utf8-character in hex-notation:

```
\u2714
```

Comment: This doesn't morph but also doesn't display correctly once on the server.  Could this be server related?  FWIW if I manually paste the char into the css it displays fine on server.